# How to obtain custom aggregate totals in UI Grid's footer

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Is there a way I could obtain a custom total in UI-Grid?

For example I have the following [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0kRRvyBkyC85MbxDceHT?p=preview)

I would like to only add up rows with names Terry Clay and Nieves Mack and display that as a total. I.E: **I would like a total of the sum of a specific number of rows**. Is it doable? I've been looking for a way to do it and got to `customTreeAggregationFn` and `customTreeAggregationFinalizerFn` as shown in the plunkr. However I'm unsure as to how to access the values in those specific rows to add them up and display as part of the footer.

Here's the code in the Plunkr

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    showGridFooter: true,
    showColumnFooter: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'name', width: '13%' },
        { field: 'address.street',aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum, width: '13%' },
        { field: 'age', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.avg, aggregationHideLabel: true, width: '13%' },
        { name: 'ageMin', field: 'age', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.min, width: '13%', displayName: 'Age for min' },
        { name: 'ageMax', field: 'age', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.max, width: '13%', displayName: 'Age for max' },
        { name: 'customCellTemplate', field: 'age', width: '14%', 
          customTreeAggregationFn : function( aggregation, fieldValue, numValue, row ) {
          if(row.entity.name.value === 'Terry Clay' || row.entity.name.value === 'Nieves Mack'){
           aggregation.value += row.entity.age;
          }
          },
          customTreeAggregationFinalizerFn: function( aggregation ) {
           aggregation.rendered = aggregation.value;
          }
        },
        { name: 'registered', field: 'registered', width: '20%', cellFilter: 'date', footerCellFilter: 'date', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.max }
    ],
    data: data,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
};
```

Please help, I've been having a bunch of problems with UI Grid and it's lack of support, so hopefully that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. In order to add up specific rows I wrote a function that returns it. [Here's the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0ESMe3MSVS2gKOnh3sbC?p=preview).

Here's the code to it.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    showGridFooter: true,
    showColumnFooter: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'name', width: '13%' },
        { field: 'address.street',aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum, width: '13%' },
        { field: 'age', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.avg, aggregationHideLabel: true, width: '13%' },
        { name: 'ageMin', field: 'age', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.min, width: '13%', displayName: 'Age for min' },
        { name: 'ageMax', field: 'age', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.max, width: '13%', displayName: 'Age for max' },
        { name: 'customCellTemplate', field: 'age', width: '14%', 
          aggregationType: function ()
          {
            if(!$scope.gridApi)
                return 0;
            var sum = 0;

            //if it is filtered/sorted you want the filtered/sorted rows only)
            var visibleRows = $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows($scope.gridApi.grid);

            for (var i = 0; i < visibleRows.length; i++) {
              if(visibleRows[i].entity.name === 'Sandoval Mclean' || visibleRows[i].entity.name === 'Nieves Mack') {

                  //you have to parse just in case the data is in string otherwise it will concatenate
                  sum += parseInt(visibleRows[i].entity.age);
              }
            }
            return sum;
          },
        },
        { name: 'registered', field: 'registered', width: '20%', cellFilter: 'date', footerCellFilter: 'date', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.max }
    ],
    data: data,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
};
```

The `aggregationType` function is where the magic happens where I only add the rows that have specific names.